# In d3, how to get the interpolated line data from a SVG line?

Tags: javascript, graphics, svg, d3.js

I display a line chart with D3 with roughly the following code (given the scale functions `x`, `y` and the float array `data`):

```
 var line = d3.svg.line()
         .interpolate("basis")
         .x(function (d, i) { return x(i); })
         .y(function (d) { return y(d); });
 d3.select('.line').attr('d', line(data));
```

Now I want to know the **vertical height of the line at a given horizontal pixel position**. The `data` array has lesser data points than pixels and the displayed line is **interpolated**, so it is not straight-forward to deduce the height of the line at a given pixel just from the `data` array.

Any hints?

Comment: Looks like a tricky problem because d3 is calculates the intermediate values for you. You might have better luck using a combination of [d3.svg.area](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-area) and d3.geom.polygon...

Comment: Would you be able to select the line (by id for example) from svg container and get its `x1`,`x2`,`y1` and `y2` attributes? (I'm sorry if i misunderstood your question)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edited 19-Sep-2012 per comments** *with many thanks to nrabinowitz!*

You will need to do some sort of search of the data returned by `getPointAtLength`. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/SVGPathElement.)

```
// Line
var line = d3.svg.line()
     .interpolate("basis")
     .x(function (d) { return i; })
     .y(function(d, i) { return 100*Math.sin(i) + 100; });

// Append the path to the DOM
d3.select("svg#chart") //or whatever your SVG container is
     .append("svg:path")
     .attr("d", line([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]))
     .attr("id", "myline");

// Get the coordinates
function findYatX(x, linePath) {
     function getXY(len) {
          var point = linePath.getPointAtLength(len);
          return [point.x, point.y];
     }
     var curlen = 0;
     while (getXY(curlen)[0] < x) { curlen += 0.01; }
     return getXY(curlen);
}

console.log(findYatX(5, document.getElementById("myline")));
```

For me this returns [5.000403881072998, 140.6229248046875].

This search function, `findYatX`, is far from efficient (runs in *O(n)* time), but illustrates the point.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the docs, this is incorrect - you would not get the point at `x=3`, you'd get the point at `pathLength=3`, which could vary widely depending on the shape of the path.

Comment: @nrabinowitz yikes, you're quite right. Not sure how I misread that. Will edit my answer when I find a real solution. Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only solution for an interpolated line is doing a search for `.getPointAtLength(i)` until `Math.abs(i - x)` is less than some threshold. A binary search might work reasonably well here. Would post an answer myself but I haven't had time :).

Comment: Yah, that's all I could think of too. See edited post. Many thanks @nrabinowitz.

Comment: This solution works for me but seems to be a bit laggy. As 2 years have passed, are there chances that there is a more optimal solution can be used now?

Comment: Look at my answer. It is very fast O(log(n)) and you can set the precision/error.

Answer (score 22):

This solution is much more efficient than the accepted answer. It's execution time is logarithmic (while accepted answer has linear complexity).

```
var findYatXbyBisection = function(x, path, error){
  var length_end = path.getTotalLength()
    , length_start = 0
    , point = path.getPointAtLength((length_end + length_start) / 2) // get the middle point
    , bisection_iterations_max = 50
    , bisection_iterations = 0

  error = error || 0.01

  while (x < point.x - error || x > point.x + error) {
    // get the middle point
    point = path.getPointAtLength((length_end + length_start) / 2)

    if (x < point.x) {
      length_end = (length_start + length_end)/2
    } else {
      length_start = (length_start + length_end)/2
    }

    // Increase iteration
    if(bisection_iterations_max < ++ bisection_iterations)
      break;
  }
  return point.y
}
```

Comment: this doesnt work when there is null value in between the path..like if we use line.undefined function of d3

Comment: great job! woks great and it is way faster than the accepted solution! so it is suitable for mouseover or scroll event.

Comment: Thanks :)  You helped me

Answer (score 0):

I have tried implementing findYatXbisection (as nicely suggested by bumbu), and I could not get it to work AS IS.

Instead of modifying the length as a function of length_end and length_start, I just decreased the length by 50% (if x < point.x) or increased by 50% (if x> point.x) but always relative to start length of zero.  I have also incorporated revXscale/revYscale to convert pixels to x/y values as set by my d3.scale functions.

```
function findYatX(x,path,error){
    var length = apath.getTotalLength()
        , point = path.getPointAtLength(length)
        , bisection_iterations_max=50
        , bisection_iterations = 0
    error = error || 0.1
    while (x < revXscale(point.x) -error || x> revXscale(point.x + error) {
        point = path.getPointAtlength(length)
        if (x < revXscale(point.x)) {
             length = length/2
        } else {
             length = 3/2*length
        }
        if (bisection_iterations_max < ++ bisection_iterations) {
              break;
        }
    }
return revYscale(point.y)
}
```

Comment: I think your algorithm will work quite badly in some cases. Also it seems to have much more iterations than bisection method.

For example if your length is 100 and your point is at 90 then your algorithm will do:
1) 90 < 100 so length = 100/2 = 50
2) 90 > 50 so length = 50*1.5 = 75
3) 90 > 75 so length = 75*1.5 = 112.5
4) 90 < 112.5 so length = 112.5/2 = 56.5
5) 90 > 56.5 so length = 56.5*1.5 = 84.75
6) 90 > 84.75 so length = 84.75*1.5 = 127.125
7) 90 < 127.125 so length = 127.125/2 = 63.5625

As you see your algorithm is just jumping around sometimes even exceeding initial length.