# How can I connect a circle to a path with a line that is perpendicular to the x axis to create an "error line"?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a scatter plot with a line of best fit. I want to draw vertical lines (residual error lines) from each data point to the regression line. How can I do this?

If possible, I would like to use a transition to rotate the line of best fit and have the error lines expand or contract as the line of best rotates. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
As pointed out, I incorrectly said the data for my line was contained within "data"; however, the line is being drawn using an array called lin_reg_results that is structured as follows:

```
var lin_reg_results = [{'x':3.4,'y':4.6},{'x':3.6,'y',2.4}...]
```

`lin_reg_results` data points were created by performing a linear regression server side and then passing the results back with ajax.

[image: My Chart]

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[x_val]; }))
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[y_val]; }))

// PLOT THE DATA POINTS

svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("transform", "translate("+50+"," + 10 + ")")
  .attr("r", 2.5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d[x_val]); })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d[y_val]); })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d[z_val]); });

// DRAW THE PATH
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d['x']; }))
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d['y']; }))

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d['x']); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d['y']); })
  .interpolate("linear"); 

svg.append("path")
  .datum(lin_reg_results)
  .attr("transform", "translate("+50+"," + 10 + ")")
  .attr("id","regression_line")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line);
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using to draw the line please? It looks like you're binding the same data to the line as you did for the points and using the same way of computing the coordinates. This would result in a line through every point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - you were correct, I had an error in the code that was posted. I've updated my question - please let me know if further details are still needed.

Comment: do you  want a vertical line straight from the line of best fit to the data point.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: I believe this can be solved using dot product vectors to find the vertical line for your point to the reference line. If you have a problem applying this, let me know and I can scour one of my apps to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append a line for each data point from the coordinates of that point to where it meets the line. The code would look something like the following (with some code adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503151/in-d3-how-to-get-the-interpolated-line-data-from-a-svg-line)):

```
d3.selectAll("line")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", function(d) { return x(d[x_val]); })
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d[x_val]); })
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return y(d[y_val]); })
  .attr("y2", function(d) {
    var line = d3.select("#regression_line").node(),
        x = x(d[x_val]);
    function getXY(len) {
      return line.getPointAtLength(len);
    }
    var curlen = 0;
    while (getXY(curlen).x < x) { curlen += 0.01; }
    return getXY(curlen).y;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for this - after doing some research, it appears that this is the correct approach. However, var line = d3.select("path.regression_line").node() returns null. I think once I figure out what is going on with that, this solution will work.

Comment: Although this will work, it doesn't look very efficient (creeping along the path until you find the point at which it crosses each x value).  Since you would presumably know the equation of the line of best fit in `y=mx+b` form, it would be best to use that equation to determine the y value of the line at the x value from the data, and then just put that y value into your y scale.

Comment: In this particular case you could even just do a linear interpolation between first and last point, no need for anything in between. The code will work in general though.

Comment: Thanks Lars and Amelia - I'm going to attempt to implement some of the suggested solutions today and will update once complete.

Comment: @Lars - I'm using a slightly modified version of your solution that is giving the me the correct values for x1,x2,y1,y2 but it is appending the line outside of the body. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Ah, you might need `svg.selectAll("line")` instead of `d3.selectAll("line")`.