# D3.js linegraph: How can I apply the interpolation also to line marker positions?

Tags: d3.js

I created a line graph with markers and apply the `basis` `interpolation` to the line to make it smoother. Unfortunately the line markers (where a tooltip is shown on mouseover) are still on their old position (where the line would be without interpolation)

Here is a simplified jsfiddle with the `basis interpolation` on line 49

http://jsfiddle.net/ndldd/tqugf0za/1/

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503151/in-d3-how-to-get-the-interpolated-line-data-from-a-svg-line) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply

```
interpolate("cardinal");
```

instead of

```
interpolate("basis");
```